# Jest mocked class dependency returns undefined if called through class being tested

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to write some unit tests for my basic CRUD app using Jest. The class I would like to test is a **repository** for my DB entity **"Project"** and it has a dependency on the **project model** which I inject into its constructor.

At the moment, I'm able to mock the project model and its components successfully and when I console log a call of the mocked function, I'm getting the expected results. However, once I instantiate my repository (test subject) with the mocked project model; I attempt to call a function on it which makes use of the mentioned mocked function and get the result **"undefined"** instead.

**To summarize my problem**, the behaviour of the mock **differs** when one of its functions is called directly as opposed to calling the mocked function indirectly through the test class and it has left me wondering what am I doing wrong for a couple of days now. Any help would be highly appreciated! Here is the minimum code in which I can reproduce the issue.

tests/repositories/project.spec.ts

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { container } from "tsyringe";
import ProjectRepository from "../../src/repositories/project";
import ProjectModel from "../../src/models/project";
import Fixtures from "../fixtures";
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';

jest.mock('../../src/models/project', () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
            model: jest.fn()
        }
      })
});

// using mocked() helper to have the types of the object being mocked types on the actual mock.
const projectModelMock = mocked<ProjectModel>(container.resolve(ProjectModel), true);

//setting resolved value to be fixture data for each function to be faked.
projectModelMock.model.findOne = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(Fixtures.SingleObject1);

console.log(projectModelMock.model.findOne()); 
// Above line Prints:
//      Promise {
//     {
//       _id: '60901d3237604b90b072ef01',
//       description: 'net core',
//       name: 'authorization server',
//       repo: 'aliboy.com'
//     }
//   }
// Works as expected when used here, doesn't work as expected when called through subject under test.

it('hopefully works', () => {
    //instantiating the class to be tested with the mocked dependency
    const testSubject = new ProjectRepository(projectModelMock); 

    //calling a class method which makes a call to the findOne() function being mocked.
    expect(testSubject.getOne()).resolves.toEqual(Fixtures.SingleObject1);
});
```

repositories/project.ts

```
import  mongoose from "mongoose";
import mongodb from "mongodb";

import { autoInjectable, singleton } from "tsyringe";
import IProjectDocument from "../models/interfaces/project";
import IResponseModel from "../models/interfaces/response";
import ProjectModel from "../models/project";
import ResponseModel from "../models/response";
import BaseRepository from "./repository";
import IDocument from "../models/interfaces/document";

@singleton()
@autoInjectable()
export default class ProjectRepository extends BaseRepository<IDocument<IProjectDocument>>{
    constructor(model: ProjectModel){
        super(model.model);
    }
```

repositories/repository.ts

```
import mongoose  from "mongoose";
import IDocument from "../models/interfaces/document";
import ResponseModel from "../models/response";

export default class BaseRepository<T>{
    model: mongoose.Model<any, any>
    constructor(model: mongoose.Model<IDocument<T>>){
        this.model = model;
    }

    getOne = async (filters = {}): Promise<ResponseModel<T>> => {
        try{
            console.log( this.model.findOne());
            //Above line prints: **undefined**
            //This is unexpected and should print Promise{object} instead.
            const result : T = await this.model.findOne(filters); //<-- **Problematic Line**
            if(result != null){
                return Promise.resolve(new ResponseModel(true, result, `Single object fetched successfully`));
            }

            return Promise.resolve(new ResponseModel(false, result, `Single object not found`));
        } catch(e){
            return Promise.reject(new ResponseModel(false, void(0), String(e)));
        }

    }
```

models/interfaces/project.ts

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

interface IProjectSchema{
    name: String,
    description: String,
    repo: String
}

export default interface IProjectDocument extends IProjectSchema, mongoose.Document {}
```

models/project.ts

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { autoInjectable, injectable, singleton } from "tsyringe";
import IDocument from "./interfaces/document";
import IModel from "./interfaces/model";
import IProjectDocument from "./interfaces/project";

@singleton()
@autoInjectable()
export default class ProjectModel implements IModel {
    schema: mongoose.Schema;
    model : mongoose.Model<IDocument<IProjectDocument>>;

    constructor() {
        this.schema =  new mongoose.Schema({
            name: String,
            description: String,
            repo: String,
            _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
        })
        this.model = mongoose.model<IDocument<IProjectDocument>>("projects", this.schema);
    }
}
```

models/interfaces/document.ts

```
import ISchema from "./schema";
import mongoose from "mongoose";


export default interface IDocument<T> extends mongoose.Document<any>{}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by setting the jest function on the test subject directly rather than setting it through the project model.

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { container } from "tsyringe";
import ProjectRepository from "../../src/repositories/project";
import ProjectModel from "../../src/models/project";
import Fixtures from "../fixtures";
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';

jest.mock('../../src/models/project', () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
            model: jest.fn()
        }
      })
});


const projectModelMock = mocked<ProjectModel>(container.resolve(ProjectModel), true);

//Below line was the problem!
// projectModelMock.model.findOne = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(Fixtures.SingleObject1); <--- TURNS OUT THIS IS NOT NEEDED
    

it('hopefully works', async() => {
    const testSubject = new ProjectRepository(projectModelMock); 

    //This one did the trick
    testSubject.model.findOne =  jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(Fixtures.SingleObject1);  // <--- HAD TO DO THIS INSTEAD

    await expect(testSubject.getOne()).resolves.toEqual(Fixtures.SingleObject1);
});
```